# Picture environment "rotating" text

Tags: diagrams, rotating

I'd like to know how can I *rotate* text in the picture environment.

I want to typeset some text from bottom-to-top, making it to appear *sideways*.

Basically, the following

```
\begin{picture}(...,...)
  \put(0,0){\rotate{-90}{Text.}}
\end{picture}
```

should be printed like

[image: There should be some text here appearing in *sideways* ... now, where did I put it again?]

(The text's background is gray, because it's funnier that way!)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(50,50)
  \put(0,0){\rotatebox{90}{Text}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```